# Word for doing something after 'peak' activity (e.g. retirement)

Tags: single-word-requests

We could say that a student learns or practices, then as an employee does the activity.

While the student learns, this could be considered 'ramping up' an activity.

What would a corresponding verb be for when a person is 'ramping down' an activity -- say working in a post-retirement environment, or using a skill only occasionally?

Comment: a phrase: *keep one's hand in*

Comment: @HippoSawrUs that should be converted to an answer!

Comment: 'Ramp down' is idiomatic.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I think they wanted only a verb or phrasal verb. I'm not sure which.

Comment: *Winding down* is the opposite of *ramping up*, but I don't know if that works for your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Tinfoil Hat: **"winding down"** ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wind-down)) is the opposite of "ramping up." For example, "As her retirement nears, she's been winding down her involvement in the project."

It's not one word, but then again, neither is "ramping up."